# How do I a string of the form "[int, int..]" and convert it to a list of int?

Tags: string, list, haskell

I have a string that looks like

```
"[1, 45, 3, 4, 54, 299]"
```

Although the length is arbitrary. There will be more than one list, that is just an example.
I want to convert it into a list of integers such as

```
[1, 45, 3, 4, 54, 299]
```

I have tried

```
strToInt :: String -> [Int]
strToInt xs = map digitToInt $ filter (`elem` ["0"..]) xs
```

But it isn't working.

```
error:
    Variable not in scope: digitToInt :: [Char] -> Int
   |
   | gh5 xs = map digitToInt $ filter (`elem` ["0"..]) xs
```

Thank you.

Comment: "But it isn't working." **that is not an adequate problem description** - how is it "not working"? Does it compile? What output do you get?

Comment: The standard function `read` will read a string in your format into a list of ints (among many other types). Try `strToInt = read`. This will crash if the input has another format, though.

Comment: I updated the error.

Comment: You're attempting to call a function called `digitToInt`. The error message is telling you that you have not imported or defined such a function, and no such function exists in Prelude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `digitToInt`, you must import `Data.Char`. You can discover this kind of thing for yourself with [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=digitToInt). (Fixing this will get you to your next problem -- there are a few to work through.)

Comment: While this is true, it won't give the OP the result they expect, but rather `"strToInt "[1, 45, 3, 4, 54, 299]"`" will give `[1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 9, 9]`. EDIT: Or rather, "Couldn't match type [Char] with [[Char]]" because of double quotes where there should be single.

Comment: @AndrewRay Well, I think actually it will give a type error first. But the process of fixing errors and debugging is an important one -- no sense getting stuck, but yes sense getting practice when you aren't stuck. So I leave those next tasks to OP; if they get stuck again, they can ask another question talking about why they feel stuck.

Comment: Yall are right. It wasn't the function I needed for that particular purpose, but I'm glad I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell already has a function that does what you want. It's called [`read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read):

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

It turns out that there's a `Read` instance for `[Int]`, so you can define `strToInt` as:

```hs
strToInt :: String -> [Int]
strToInt = read
```

Given this, however, if you give an invalid string that doesn't match the expected format, it will throw the following error:

```
> strToInt "incorrect"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

If you want more robust handling, you can look at [`Text.Read.readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) and [`Prelude.reads`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reads), as Daniel Wagner pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for the reminder. I always jump straight to the custom parser for its ability to define the input format, so I forget about `reads`.